# Tutorial for Payway to integrate in iPhone app?

Tags: ios, api, transactions, paypal

I want to use PayWay e-com to do transaction from my app.Since I am new to this technology, I am not sure where to start and how to integrate it in my iPhone app which has php backend.

Can anyone please suggest some good Tutorial to start with this? I found there are two ways to use it in our app.

1.PayWay Net

2.PayWay API

I want to work with 2nd one ie.,PayWay API. Please suggest some good reference which will be useful in integrating to ios app.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a free test facility by contacting [PayWay technical helpdesk](https://www.payway.com.au/core/ContactHelpdeskView).  This will give you an access to the system to download sample code and the software you need.

You have tagged your issue PayPal.  PayPal is only supported through PayWay Net, and not PayWay API.

To use PayWay Net you redirect the cardholder's browser to the PayWay website.  With PayWay API, your system talks directly to the PayWay server.  The advantage of PayWay Net is that your systems do not need to process credit card numbers and pass PCI-DSS.  The advantage of PayWay API is that you can build a more seamless integration and handle situations where the cardholder can not be presented with a web browser.

(Disclaimer: I work for Westpac).

Comment: :Thank you for your response to my post.Can you just tell me how to start PayWay? Should I need need any login for downloading API? or any Sandbox kind of thing is there in PayWay just like PayPal? I am in Panic bcz I am very new to this this.

Comment: Yes, you need a login to do test transactions which is like PayPal's sandbox.

Comment: Thank You WW. .Should I contact Payway helpdesk to get login credentials even for testing purpose also? or any signup option provided?

Comment: Yes, best to contact the help desk even for a free test facility.